# Android Facebook Album cover photo

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to fetch [Cover Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/album/picture) of an album using Graph API.

Here is my code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("type", "thumbnail");
        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + albumID + "/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        Log.v("TAG", "Facebook Photos response: " + response);
                      }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Using above code, I am getting  below response:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000�Photoshop"}, error: null}
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong with my request and how I can get a cover photo of an album?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SahdevRajput74: what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After googling, I found a solution and its working fine for me.

I have changed **Bundle** parameters as below:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("type", "thumbnail");
params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
```

Rest of code as it.
After changing, I am getting proper response same as I get in Graph API browser:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s180x540\/13782019_1735895746671060_1058868038400371031_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=506c19df47791a4b7fcfc362eeed0676&oe=5B92AA68"}}, error: null}
```